# How to format large value on Y axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting volume data of Crypto getting from exchanges which are 8-9 digits big. I know I could format it by adding a separator but what if I want to show it in Ks?, for instance, 100,000 should be shown as 100K?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matplotlib.ticker. I created an example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#Random Data
y = np.arange(1000, 2000, 100)
x = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

# y / 1000 -> K
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: 
'{:,.2f}'.format(y/1000) + 'K'))

ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Graph Title')
plt.show()
```

[image]